# How to query for articles without a data category?

Tags: soql, knowledge, sosl

I can query articles with specific data categories, for example:

```
SELECT Title FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE PublishStatus='online' WITH DATA CATEGORY Geography__c ABOVE usa__c
```

But what if I want only the articles that do not have a value set  for the Geography category?. There doesn't seem to be a simple way to negate this query.

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: There is no error, the question is around how to do the opposite on that query. For example using WITHOUT doesn't compile because I guess it doesn't exist.

Comment: I thought I had it with this "SELECT Title FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE PublishStatus='online' AND Language = 'en_US' WITH DATA CATEGORY Product__c ABOVE All__c" but it includes the 'All' category. If your process is such that you never use that value it might be of interest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same problem today, and solved it like this:

```
Select Id, ArticleNumber, Title from ArticleType__kav where Id not in (Select ParentId from ArticleType__DataCategorySelection) and PublishStatus = 'Online'
```

You should replace ArticleType__kav and ArticleType__DataCategorySelection based on the name of your Article Type.

For example, if you have an Article Type called "Answer", the query would look like this:

```
Select Id, ArticleNumber, Title from Answer__kav where Id not in (Select ParentId from Answer__DataCategorySelection) and PublishStatus = 'Online'
```

What it does is looks for articles where there is no record in the DataCategorySelection object for that article type.  Only articles with a Data Category assigned will have a record in that object.

Comment: Is there a way to do this that is *not* category specific?

Comment: @sfdcfox - any input on this? This seems to be an expensive query (especially when it's being run on key press), plus it only works on category-specific queries.