# Knowledge article-data category filtering not working with translations

Tags: soql, knowledge, servicecloud, articles

I wanted to apply filter to the article type, and filtering criteria was that 
**show only articles with data categories**. So, I created the following SOQL after reviewing [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67785/how-to-query-for-articles-without-a-data-category):

```
SELECT ID, Title, UrlName, KnowledgeArticleId 
FROM Troubleshooting__kav 
WHERE Language = 'en_US'  
AND  Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM Troubleshooting__DataCategorySelection) 
AND  publishStatus = 'Online'  
ORDER BY Title ASC
```

The above soql works well if the language is English (`en_US`), but if I change the language to Spanish (`es_MX`) then it doesn't return any data. I have Spanish translated articles setup in my sandbox. If I remove the following filter

```
AND  Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM Troubleshooting__DataCategorySelection)
```

Spanish articles then appear fine.

Comment: Indeed, this looks like an issue, unless someone can explain why translated articles, eventhough having a data category are not being displayed as a result from the SOQL you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, unless someone comes up with a solution related exactly to the `articleType__DataCategorySelection` situation posted above, this is what I have used to filter articles using [WITH DATA CATEGORY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with_datacategory.htm) clause and filtering with the top most data category level:

`WITH DATA CATEGORY Topics__c Below All__c`

Final SOQL (Article Type= **Troubleshooting__kav** ) :

```
SELECT ID, Title, UrlName, KnowledgeArticleId 
FROM Troubleshooting__kav 
WHERE Language = 'en_US'  
AND   publishStatus = 'Online'  
WITH  DATA CATEGORY Topics__c Below All__c
ORDER BY Title ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just getting same issue and above given workaround is not going to help because I need to add **NOT IN filter** which I am achieving by the datacategoryselection and then filtering (as there is no option for not in data category SOQL- WITH, BELOW and AT only supported).

It seems salesforce issue; if it returns value for Language='en_US' then it should return value for Language='ja' as well.